# How do I update my EmberJS data model in a route after receiving new records via a websocket?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using a websocket to receive newly created models in my EmberJS app.

```
websocket.onMessage((data) => {
  this.store.push(data);
});
```

This works perfectly as I can confirm using the Ember inspector.

Annoyingly this doesn't update my existing template though. I am showing a list of items using:

```
model: function(){
  return this.store.findAll("posts");
}
```

There's a lot of questions like this one on StackOverflow but none seem to answer the real question. Anyone got an idea how this should be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

So this actually does do the job, but it pushes the object to the bottom of my list. Turns out it's simpler to just do this in the router:

```
websocket.onMessage((data) => {
  this.refresh();
});
```